Blank pop up appears when buying subscription products from Microsoft store. UWP, MS Subscriptions, Unity
I am currently experiencing a problem with Microsoft store API (Windows.Services.Store) in Unity UWP build of the game. I have my own API built on top of Windows.Services.Store
Situation is as following:

Pop-up appears.
I press "buy now."
It is showing a loading screen.
The pop-up becomes a blank sheet with a outlined space for some information (but without actual information).

At step 4 the only thing I can do with this pop-up is to close it by pressing on X in the top-right corner which results into the status of purchase NotPurchased.
I have figured out that the problem is in the Windows.Service.Store API. The execution is stuck in the process of awaiting RequestPurchaseAsync function.
awaited function where the execution is stuck
Buying a subscription. Image
Blank pop-up. Image
I have tried updating API, changing version of XAML, looking for similar problems in other projects on the web.
UPD: I have found a following error Event Viewer:
ReactControlViewer.OnWebViewScriptNotify. Message is null or unsupported. Returning early. Original value: {"message":"status","version":"20240512.1_k8s","data":"https://www.microsoft.com/store/purchaseui/purchase-ui/static/js/client.47b6aac7.js script loaded"}
Error: The operation completed successfully.
Function: OnWebViewScriptNotify
Source: .\src\Purchase\Store.Purchase\Controls\ReactControlViewer.cs (349)

Have you checked if the Microsoft Store's IP is blocked or not?

Open the Microsoft Store app and try to purchase something, Just check if the pay window shows the same. If it is, then it related to the Store app itself.

@RoyLi-MSFT How do I check it?

Btw, consumable InApps do work as intended.

Just like what @Ax1le said, you could test purchase in the Microsoft Store app to see if the purchase window could show correctly.

From microsoft guidelines:
Selling subscriptions to customers directly via the Store is not supported at this time. Subscriptions are available for in-app purchases of digital products only.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/enable-subscription-add-ons-for-your-app
@RoyLi-MSFT

Have you checked if this happens on different devices and different network environment? The RequestPurchaseAsync  just launches the payment window and receive the result. The payment window is window that managed by the system. UWP API can't modify the window.

@RoyLi-MSFT
It is reproducible on other devices and network environments as well.

OK. Does this behavior happen in a normal UWP project (not in a Unity project ) on your side? I could not reproduce the same behavior in a normal UWP project.

@RoyLi-MSFT Well, the project is in Unity, but I have my own dll which handles everything regarding the Windows.Services.Store.

@RoyLi-MSFT I have also noticed that StoreCollectionData is null for the given product (and for all the others including working inapps)

@RoyLi-MSFT I have found a following error in Event Viewer:
ReactControlViewer.OnWebViewScriptNotify. Message is null or unsupported. Returning early. Original value: {"message":"status","version":"20240512.1_k8s","data":"https://www.microsoft.com/store/purchaseui/purchase-ui/static/js/client.47b6aac7.js script loaded"}
Error: The operation completed successfully.
Function: OnWebViewScriptNotify
Source: .\src\Purchase\Store.Purchase\Controls\ReactControlViewer.cs (349)

hi @GlebsMedvedevs did you ever solve this issue? We are having the same problem on a Java application :(
